# Pass two UIElements as CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism

I have a `Prism` MVVM app, can easily pass one `UIElement` as a `CommandParameter` to ViewModel's `Command`. But now I want to pass two UIElements. Using this XAML:

```
<Button.CommandParameter>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource DummyMultiConverter}">
        <Binding ElementName="PasswordBoxType"/>
        <Binding ElementName="PasswordBoxRetype"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
```

Using this `Converter`:

```
public class DummyMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And a simple `DelegateCommand` in ViewModel:

```
private DelegateCommand<object> _commandCloseDialogOK;
public DelegateCommand<object> CommandCloseDialogOK =>
    _commandCloseDialogOK ??
    (_commandCloseDialogOK = new DelegateCommand<object>(commandParameter=> CommandCloseDialogOKExecute(commandParameter)));

public virtual void CommandCloseDialogOKExecute(object commandParameter)
{
    RaiseRequestClose(new DialogResult(ButtonResult.OK));
}

public virtual bool CanExecuteCommandCloseDialogOK()
{
    return true;
}
```

When it runs - `Convert` method gets `values` correctly, as an array of 2 `PasswordBoxes`. But CommandCloseDialogOKExecute gets its **commandParameter** parameter as an array of two **nulls**. Same happens if I define **commandParameter** as **object[]** instead of **object**. What should I do that **commandParameter** would be array of two `PasswordBoxes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are using MVVM you really should not pass view-related data, like UIElement's, to the view model.

Assuming that you know that and this really is a simplified depiction to illustrate your issue, the problem is that the framework explicitly clears the array that is passed into the Convert method before the value that Convert returns gets applied to the binding. The result is that it applies the now-empty array (nulls):

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/MultiBindingExpression.cs,1267

You can avoid this by creating another array in your Convert method:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return new []{values[0], values[1]};
}
```

Comment: *"the problem is that the array your multi-converter is returning is a local parameter that goes out of scope when the Convert-method returns."* I don't believe that that is correct. It's an array - a reference type - which cannot "go out of scope" if you still have a reference to it (the return value in this case)....

Comment: ...Rather, the reason is that the framework explicitly clears the array that is passed in to the Convert method before the value that Convert returns gets applied to the binding. The result is that it applies the now-empty array (nulls):  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/MultiBindingExpression.cs,1267

Comment: You are right of course, thanks for clearing that up! The code smell was holding on to an object (Array in this case) that you do not have direct control of.